# Why am I seeing the following warnings in one Xcode installation, but not another?

Tags: ios, xcode

The code for our project works fine for one developer in Xcode 4, but it was given to another and they can't get it to build.  Both of us have screen shots showing our particular situations. There are 10 warnings but it still builds for us on our side and the app works fine.

This is the error screen shot:

[image: Xcode error]

There are 2 files missing but they are not important.

How can I resolve these warnings?

Comment: We are not xCode or your collegues. We cann't compile your code, even more - we cann't see it. Show please anything.

Comment: it would help if you gave us the text of those warnings--generally more information makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: By "build" do you mean "archive"?  If so, make sure in your scheme that when you do an "archive" that it is using the expected build configuration (normally "release" but sometimes custom like "distribution").  Some settings, such as scheme mappings, are not saved with the project and can cause discrepancies with building.

Comment: this is the error screen shot, http://www.box.net/s/0idf7nml404yr8hb31t3

Comment: there are 2 files missing but they are not important. app works fine for us.

Comment: i will check that sam. thank you.

Comment: In the future, don't link to an image, just embed it in the question, like I've edited your post to do.  In fact, you're probably better off listing the text from your errors instead of just taking a screenshot in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

The files are located on Yahelena's desktop.  You need to include them in the project by using the "copy items into destination group's folder" when dragging, so that they will work for every one who has the project.

Comment: looks good...let me try.

Comment: +1 I've seen this happen on my development team in the past as well.  This is definitely a problem that will break your build.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the missing files, you have three classes of warnings here:

- Unused variables: If you declare variables and don't use them within a method, LLVM will warn you about this.  This is generally an indication of either dead code that you can remove or an incomplete implementation of a method.
- Deprecated methods: You've probably started compiling this project on a newer version of the iOS SDK, so certain methods that you'd used in the past are now marked as deprecated.  This is a warning from Apple that these methods will be removed at some time in the future.  You should find the correct up-to-date equivalents for these methods and replace your calls to deprecated methods with the newer, better way of doing things.  Odds are, the replacement for a deprecated method is indicated right in the documentation if you search for the old method.
- Incompatible pointer types: This can indicate a serious logic error, where you are trying to pass the wrong kind of object into a method or variable, so this should be examined carefully.

The reason why this project may have compiled cleanly before, but is showing warnings now, is that you've most likely started compiling this on a newer version of Xcode which uses the iOS 5.0 SDK and the LLVM compiler.  The LLVM compiler picks up problems that GCC let slide, and your deprecated methods most likely were marked as such in iOS 5.0.

As a comment, I highly recommmend setting the compiler flag to make warnings turn into errors, because Objective-C lets you get away with certain things at compile time that would crash your application at runtime, only marking these problems as warnings.